# Perl get string between 2 patterns

Tags: regex, perl

I have a log file that has this pattern several times:

```
Toggle('AFDACAAAAAIAAAA')" class="Failure">ABC</a>
```

I have this code line to get the entire line that has this pattern
but I’m only interested in the ABC string ( that may be any other string )

```
print "$line" if $line =~ /Toggle\('[A-Z]*'\)" class="Failure">.*<\/a>/g;
```

Can I do that with regex ?

Comment: What's wrong with `>[^<]+</a>`?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a capture group you can use a look ahead and the `\K` anchor:

```
print $& if $line =~ /Toggle\('[A-Z]*'\)" class="Failure">\K.*(?=<\/a>)/;
```

`\K` will basically throw away everything that has been matched before it - but it still has to match.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the bit that you want. It'll be in `$1`. (Oh, and you don't need the `/g`.)

```
print $1 if $line =~ /Toggle\('[A-Z]*'\)" class="Failure">(.*)<\/a>/;
```